# bash + test if folder is empty but exclude files with a leading dot

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, directory, ls

We used the following approach in order to verify if a folder is empty:

```
[[ "$(ls -A /var/folder)" ]] && echo "not empty"
```

on `/var/folder`, we did the following:

```
ls -l /var/folder
total 0
```

indeed we not get any output.

**but when we run the shell as**

```
[[ "$(ls -A /var/folder)" ]] && echo "not empty"
```

then it prints

```
not empty
```

so what we found is that the folder include files
that have leading dot, as the following:

```
ls -la /var/folder
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 kafka kafka   47 Jan 19 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 42 kafka kafka 4096 Jan 19 10:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka kafka    0 Jan 19 17:22 .kafka_cleanshutdown
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka kafka    0 Jan 19 15:16 .lock
```

so the question is how to verify if a folder is empty
but ignore the existence of the files that lead with "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want dot files to be seen, leave off the `-A`!

```
[[ "$(ls /var/folder)" ]] && echo "not empty"
```

But you don't need even need to use `ls`;
you can do this entirely in the shell:

```
file_list=(/var/folder/*)
[[ "${file_list[*]}" != "/var/folder/*" ]] && echo "not empty"
```

This expands the `/var/folder/*` wildcard pattern ("glob"). 
If there are non-hidden files,
then `file_list` will be a list of their names. 
If there aren't any,
then `file_list` will be just the literal string `/var/folder/*`.

There's a bug in this: if the directory contains a single file
whose name is literally `*`,
then `${file_list[*]}` will be the literal string `/var/folder/*`
and the above code will fail (indicating that the directory is empty). 
You can fix that by doing

```
shopt -s nullglob
file_list=(/var/folder/*)
[[ "${file_list[*]}" != "" ]] && echo "not empty"
shopt -u nullglob
```

Of course a robust script
would check the setting of `nullglob` at the beginning
and then restore that setting at the end, rather than just unsetting it.

This is written for bash and won't work in all shells.

Answer (score 1):

You may expand `*` in the directory and count how many names it matches.  If it matches zero names, the directory is empty.  The `*` pattern does not match hidden names ("files with a leading dot") by default.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

set -- /var/folder/*

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo '/var/folder is empty'
fi
```

`"$#"` is the number of elements in the list of positional parameters, which we set with `set` to the visible names in the directory in question.

In `bash` you may use an array if you wish:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

names=( /var/folder/* )

if [ "${#names[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo '/var/folder is empty'
fi

unset -v names
```

We set `nullglob` in the above code snippets to make the pattern be removed completely if it does not match anything.  A more portable variant without using `nullglob` would be to use `set` as in the first variation, and then test `$1` for existence:

```
set -- /var/folder/*

if [ ! -e "$1" ] && [ ! -h "$1" ]; then
    echo '/var/folder is empty'
fi
```

Note that we need to test with `-h` whether the name in `$1` is a symbolic link, otherwise we would not be able to detect broken symbolic links.